# It is possible to upload List<Class> to firebase Realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Simple class named **Questions** which contain :

```
public class Questions {
String question,correctAns;
String[] incorretAns;

public Questions() {
}

public Questions(String question, String correctAns, String[] incorretAns) {
    this.question = question;
    this.correctAns = correctAns;
    this.incorretAns = incorretAns;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public String getCorrectAns() {
    return correctAns;
}

public void setCorrectAns(String correctAns) {
    this.correctAns = correctAns;
}

public String[] getIncorretAns() {
    return incorretAns;
}

public void setIncorretAns(String[] incorretAns) {
    this.incorretAns = incorretAns;
}
```

}

and I want to upload it as a `List<Questions> questionsList` list to firebase real-time database it is possible to upload!.

I have tried to upload it but the firebase real-time database gives an exception: something like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Questions")
                        .child("randomID")
                        .setValue(questionsList);
```

And it gives Exception like this:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Serializing Arrays is not supported, please 
use Lists instead
```

And there is any other way to **upload this type of data** any help will be appreciated!

Comment: does your `Question` class extend or implements `Serializable`?

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal no it not extend or implements `Serializable`

Comment: Can you share the complete code of Questions class?

Comment: @SujalKumar I added complete code of `Questions` classs now you can check

Comment: @SujalKumar I have done some changes now you can check

Comment: @Cynthia Change the type of **incorrectAns** from **String[]** to **List<String>**. Let me know if this changes anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `String[] incorretAns;` that's why you are getting this expectation:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Serializing Arrays is not 
supported, please 
use Lists instead
```

So instead of `String[] incorretAns` you can use options individually like:

```
String OptionA, OptionB, OptionC //or whatever you like
```

then you will not receive any errors I hope it helps you!

Comment: It seems like it will work thank you!